# Как продолжить установку на удаленном сервере?

Tags: linux, debian, curl

Делаю деплой через Gitlab CI. Одной из задач выполнения скрипта после деплоя. Решил использовать curl. Устанавливаю его с помощью: apt-get install curl, однако при такой установки запрашивается разрешение на продолжение.

```
$ apt-get install curl
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 libcurl4-openssl-dev
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-doc libcurl3-dbg libidn11-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev
  libssh2-1-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl libcurl3 libcurl4-openssl-dev
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 797 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Что сделать, чтобы либо не запрашивалось данное разрешение, либо отправить Y для продолжения?

Comment: `apt-get -y install curl`, -y - автоматически yes, вот [здесь](http://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install) подробнее ответ дан

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!